# How to join on price but allow for +/- 30% difference MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to join two tables in MySQL Workbench on product price, but allow for a +/- 30% variance. For example, if one table has a product for $10 and the other table has the product for $13, that product would still display in the result set. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Thank you all. What I am looking for is:

if you were to join Table A:

[image]

And Table B:

[image]

It would return Products 123 and 456, but not 789

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results . Joining on a price column seems . . . unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on` logic you describe is:

```
on t1.price >= t2.price * 0.7 and t1.price <= t2.price * 1.3
```

However, I am suspicious that this solves a real problem.

EDIT:

For your sample data:

```
select a.productId, a.price, b.price
from a join
     b
     on a.productId = b.productId and
        a.price >= 0.7 * b.price and a.price <= 1.3 * b.price;
```

Comment: i removed mine comment, this calculation keeps the query *"sargable"* (can use the index on price if anny) which is much better.  + 1 .. *"However, I am suspicious that this solves a real problem."* Iám pretty sure the topicstarter needs to join on a product_id, product_number, ean code also in combination with this

Comment: @Brad . . . Is there a reason why you prefer the more complicated expression in Mandy's answer over this one?  I noticed that you unaccepted this answer.

Comment: *"Is there a reason why you prefer the more complicated expression in Mandy's answer over this one?"* i geuss @Brad wants to have a query which returns bad results `productId` is not taking in account in that query it not only a more complicated expression